# php foreach loop isn't putting values of array_merge in desired order

Tags: php

If I fill in this form as the following:

```
<input type=number name=extra-count[0]> <!--value submitted: 4 -->
<input type=text name=extra-product[0]> <!--value submitted: product A -->
<input type=number name=extra-count[1]> <!--value submitted: 5 -->
<input type=text name=extra-product[1]> <!--value submitted: product B -->
```

Than I have this code:

```
foreach(array_merge($_POST['extra-count'],$_POST['extra-product']) as $text) {
    if(false === empty($text)){
        $message .= "\r\n".$text;
    }
}
```

To output this:

```
4 poduct A
5 product B
```

but it'll output this instead:

```
4
5
product A
product B
```

What can I do to get the first output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have always the same length on each array. You can give a try with something like this.

```
foreach($_POST['extra-count'] as $key => $text) {
    if(false === empty($text)){
        $message .= "\r\n".$text . " " . $_POST['extra-product'][$key];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this :

```
foreach($_POST['extra-count'] as $key => $value) {
            if(false === empty($text)){
                $message .= "\r\n$_POST['extra-count'][$key] $_POST['extra_product'][$key]";
            }
        }
```

Note that you can replace `$_POST['extra-count'][$key]` with `$value`, but i thought it would be easier to understand that way.

Moreover, i don't think you understood how array_merge works. You should check it out [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
foreach(array_combine($_POST['extra-count'],$_POST['extra-product']) as $key => $text) {
    if(false === empty($text)){
        $message .= "\r\n".$key.' '.$text;
    }
}
```